# How to pass a large number of dataframe columns to numpy vectorize as argument

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, vectorization, apply

I've got a dataframe with exactly 31 columns and, for example, 100 rows.

I need to create a list with 100 dictionaries that have values processed from the different 31 columns.

I am currently using `apply()` function to do this:

```
my_df.apply(lambda row: _build_data(row, param1, param2, param3), axis=1)
```

But now I want to explore the numpy `vectorize()` Possibilities. The problem is, from what I'm reading, I should pass each column to it as a separate argument:

```
np.vectorize(_build_data)(my_df[col1], my_df[col2], ..., my_df[col31], param1, param2, param3)
```

This does not look pythonic, nor do I want to have to define a function with 34 arguments.

Do you know if there is another way to do this?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: `np.vectorize` is not a speed tool.  Despite the name it isn't the 'vectorization' that will speed up you code.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from the [np.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html): *the vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.*

Therefore as hpaulj already said, it won't speed up your code

However, if you want to use it anyway, you don't have to type all your columns, just use a list comprehension:

```py
np.vectorize(_build_data)([my_df[c] for c in list(my_df)], param1, param2, param3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you were trying to use `np.vectorize` because you read that numpy 'vectorization' is a way of speeding up `pandas` code.

```
In [29]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), columns=['A','B','C'])                  
In [30]: df                                                                                    
Out[30]: 
   A   B   C
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11
```

The slow, row by row, approach to taking the row mean:

```
In [31]: df.apply(lambda row: np.mean(row), axis=1)                                            
Out[31]: 
0     1.0
1     4.0
2     7.0
3    10.0
dtype: float64
```

The fast numpy method:

```
In [32]: df.to_numpy()                                                                         
Out[32]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
In [33]: df.to_numpy().mean(axis=1)                                                            
Out[33]: array([ 1.,  4.,  7., 10.])
```

That is, we get an array of the dataframe values, and use a fast compiled method to calculate row means.

But to make something like a dictionary for each row:

```
In [35]: df.apply(lambda row: {str(k):k for k in row}, axis=1)                                 
Out[35]: 
0        {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2}
1        {'3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5}
2        {'6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8}
3    {'9': 9, '10': 10, '11': 11}
dtype: object
```

We have to iterate on array rows, just like we do with the dataframe `apply`:

```
In [36]: [{str(k):k for k in row} for row in df.to_numpy()]                                    
Out[36]: 
[{'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2},
 {'3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5},
 {'6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8},
 {'9': 9, '10': 10, '11': 11}]
```

The array approach is faster:

```
In [37]: timeit df.apply(lambda row: {str(k):k for k in row}, axis=1)                          
1.13 ms ± 702 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [38]: timeit [{str(k):k for k in row} for row in df.to_numpy()]                             
40.8 µs ± 157 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

But the `apply` method returns a dataframe, not a list.  I suspect most of the extra time is in that step.

`np.vectorize` (and `np.frompyfunc`) can also be used to iterate on an array, but the default is to iterate on elements, not rows or columns.  In general they are slower than the more explicit iteration (as I do in [36]).

A clumsy way of making a dataframe from the list:

```
In [53]: %%timeit 
    ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame(['one','two','three','four'],columns=['d'])   
    ...: df1['d'] =[{str(k):k for k in row} for row in df.to_numpy()]                                                                                       
572 µs ± 18.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: @hjpaulj thank you for the detailed respose. as df.to_numpy does not preserve column names, I explored time with df.to_dict('records') and both it and apply are quite similar. I will continue to use apply since I have not found any other approach that makes it noticeably faster for my code purposes.

Comment: `dt,to_records()` makes a structured array