# More effictient alternative to scipy.stats expect function

Tags: python, scipy

I am working on a simple simulation for a stock of products. In specific, I want to calculate the expected shortage of products for various servicelevels. For example, if I assume that the demand of a product follows a normal distribution with a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 20, for a servicelevel of 90% it would be necessary to have 125.63 units of the product on stock. And I would then still expect a shortage of 0.9469 units:

[image]

My current approach the problem is the following:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

# Create an exemplary dataset
idx = pd.Index(range(0, 1000), name='productid')
df = pd.DataFrame({'loc': np.random.normal(100, 30, 1000),
               'scale': np.random.normal(20, 5, 1000)}, index=idx)

# Calculate quantile
df['quantile'] = norm.ppf(0.9, df['loc'], df['scale'])

# Calculate expected shortage
df['shortage'] = df.apply(lambda row: norm(row['loc'], row['scale'])\
.expect(lambda x: x-row['quantile'], lb=row['quantile']), axis=1)
```

The code is actually working quiet well, but there is a problem with performance though. The calculation of the expected shortage takes around 15 seconds for 1000 products. In the real dataset I have 10000 products and I need to repeat the operation around 100 times as I want to do the simulation for various servicelevels.

So if anyone knows a more efficient alternative to the scipy.stats expect function, or knows how to boost performance by tweaking the existing code, I would be really happy.

Comment: The speed problem isn't with `norm` itself, but with having to `apply` it once for each row.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, but with the scipy.stats expect function, there is no alternative to that. Obviously, `norm(df['loc'], df['scale']).expect(lambda x: x-df['quantile'], lb=df['quantile'])` will cause an error. So I am asking for an alternative

Comment: The answer that I just wrote, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60886249/how-to-pass-a-large-number-of-dataframe-columns-to-numpy-vectorize-as-argument, about an alternative to dataframe `apply` might be relevant.  `apply` seems to be slower than row iteration on a numpy array, especially if you don't need to create a new data frame.